# Hide DIV if another DIV is active or visible with css/js

Tags: javascript, magento2.4, css, jquery

Trying to hide DIV if another DIV is active or visible with css/js.
Basically if an item is out of stock I would like to hide my custom div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery'], function(jquery) {
    jquery(document).ready(function(){
        if(document.getElementByClass("stock.unavailable").style.visibility == "visible") {
    document.getElementByClass("left-stock").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
      
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

@shaun try the below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(!$('.stock.available').is(":visible"))
  {
    $('.left-stock').remove(); // you can also use .hide()
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using jQuery, so let me provide you with a corrected version of your code i hope useful this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery'], function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if($(".stock.unavailable").is(":visible")) {
            $(".left-stock").css("visibility", "hidden");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

- Replaced **document.getElementByClass** with **$(".stock.unavailable")** to
  use jQuery's selector for elements with the specified class.
- Used the **is(":visible")** method to check if the element with class
  "stock unavailable" is visible.
- Changed **document.getElementByClass("left-stock").style.visibility** to
  **$(".left-stock").css("visibility", "hidden")** to set the visibility of
  the element with class "left-stock" to "hidden".